# Can I Use ChromeCast to get Audio from TV

Tags: android, chromecast

I know my question doesn't contain code, but was advised to post here.

I know ChromeCast is designed to  play Audio/Video on TV or media player.

But basically I am evaluating  if there is anyway I can use ChromeCast hardware and API to get audio from media player/TV and play on an android phone. Exactly reverse of what's its designed to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No. Chromecast cannot receive a signal from the TV, as it is connected to an HDMI *input* not *output*.

This has been answered before [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/X1Hn3sOnE5U), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/5itmr7/reverse_chrome_cast/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/6404mj/can_a_chromecast_audio_work_in_reverse_like_can_i/), and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/4dij95/can_you_reverse_cast_to_your_phone_or_tablet_or_pc/), among others.

You can [view the docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers) for further information, but there unfortunately won't be any that will help you with this specific goal!